# VB.NET Deserialize JSON - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type .Customer[]' because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am working on a system which will send off a POST or GET request to a web API in VB.NET.

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to do convert the returing JSON string into a VB object.

I am getting the following error when trying to deserialize the response.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ProjectName.Customer[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'customers.id', line 1, position 19.

The JSON string the API returns to me is:

> {"customers":{"id":"CU0004FEY6D7HA","created_at":"2018-10-13T13:30:21.320Z","email":"test@test.com","given_name":"Joe","family_name":"Bloggs","company_name":null,"address_line1":"1 Street Name","address_line2":"","address_line3":null,"city":"London","region":null,"postal_code":"SW1A 1AA","country_code":"GB","language":"en","swedish_identity_number":null,"danish_identity_number":null,"phone_number":null,"metadata":{}}}

I have created a class for the object.

VB.NET isn't my strongest skill since I mainly work with PHP.

Can anyone offer an helpful suggestions?

```
Public Class CustomerWrapper
    Public customers() As Customer
End Class

Public Class Metadata
    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As String
End Class

Public Class Customer

    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As String
    Public Property created_at() As String
        Get
            Return m_created_at
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_created_at = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_created_at As String
    Public Property email() As String
        Get
            Return m_email
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_email = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_email As String
    Public Property given_name() As String
        Get
            Return m_given_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_given_name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_given_name As String
    Public Property family_name() As String
        Get
            Return m_family_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_family_name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_family_name As String
    Public Property address_line1() As String
        Get
            Return m_address_line1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_address_line1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_address_line1 As String
    Public Property address_line2() As String
        Get
            Return m_address_line2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_address_line2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_address_line2 As String
    Public Property address_line3() As String
        Get
            Return m_address_line3
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_address_line3 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_address_line3 As String
    Public Property city() As String
        Get
            Return m_city
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_city = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_city As String
    Public Property region() As String
        Get
            Return m_region
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_region = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_region As String
    Public Property postal_code() As String
        Get
            Return m_postal_code
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_postal_code = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_postal_code As String
    Public Property country_code() As String
        Get
            Return m_country_code
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_country_code = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_country_code As String
    Public Property language() As String
        Get
            Return m_language
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_language = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_language As String
    Public Property phone_number() As String
        Get
            Return m_phone_number
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_phone_number = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_phone_number As String
    Public metadata() As Metadata
End Class
```

The code calling Json is

```
Dim response = apiCall.CallApi()

        'Dim customerId = customers("id")

        Dim customerWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of CustomerWrapper)(response)
        Dim customers = customerWrapper.customers
```

Comment: Change the `CustomerWrapper` `customers()` declaration in`Public Property customers() As Customer`. You don't need those backing fields. Use Auto properties (e.g., `Public Property id() As String`, `Public Property family_name() As String` etc. and nothing else.) You should also use a `JsonProperty` attribute (e.g., `<JsonProperty("family_name")> Public Property FamilyName() As String)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you have omitted the `Property` keyword from a couple of the members in your classes, which changes the semantics of the parentheses.

For example, in your `CustomerWrapper` class, you have declared the `customers` member like this:

```
Public customers() As Customer
```

Since the declaration does not have the `Property` keyword, this means that `customers` is a *field* in the class and the parenthesis here mean that it is an array.  This is actually the same as declaring the field with the parentheses after the data type:

```
Public customers As Customer()   ' Field - array of Customer
```

Conversely, in a property declaration, the parentheses after the name mean something entirely different: here, they denote an empty parameter list.  (A property is actually a type of method, so it can have parameters, though most properties do not.  The parentheses after the property name are optional if the property does not have any parameters.)

```
Public Property customers() As Customer   ' Property - single Customer
```

So, the bottom line is you are trying to deserialize a single customer object into a `customers` field that is declared as an array, resulting in the exception you see.

To fix, just add the `Property` keyword as shown above.  You will also need to fix the `metadata` field in your `Customer` class; it has the same problem.

As an FYI, you can simplify your code a lot by getting rid of the backing fields.  None of your properties have any logic in them, so you can omit the implementations and use [*auto-implemented properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties) instead (basically the compiler generates the backing fields and get/set boilerplate for you behind the scenes).  I would also get rid of the optional parentheses on the property names while you're at it.

With these changes, your classes would look like this, which is much more readable IMO:

```
Public Class CustomerWrapper
    Public Property customers As Customer
End Class

Public Class Metadata
    Public Property id As String
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property created_at As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property given_name As String
    Public Property family_name As String
    Public Property address_line1 As String
    Public Property address_line2 As String
    Public Property address_line3 As String
    Public Property city As String
    Public Property region As String
    Public Property postal_code As String
    Public Property country_code As String
    Public Property language As String
    Public Property phone_number As String
    Public Property metadata As Metadata
End Class
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vEnbnI